# Ответ от сервера. Простой клиент-сервер

Tags: java, android, клиент-сервер

Для дипломной работы нужно написать небольшой сервер для обращения к базе с помощью Android устройства. Сервер должен получить запрос, сделать выборку и отправить результат обратно. С помощью чего это реализовать?

Сервер:

```
public class ServerMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean running;
    try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(51719)) {
        System.out.println("Сервер запущен! (51719)");
        running = true;
        while(running) {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Кто-то подключился...");
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            String message = "Вы подключены к серверу.";
            printWriter.write(message);
            printWriter.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Клиент:

```
public class ClientMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.199.3", 51719)) {
        InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
        String message = bufferedReader.readLine();
        System.out.println(message);
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

P.S: Пока что хочу реализовать с компьютера, потом буду с Android'a.

Comment: библиотеки какие лучше использовать или что? вообще на сокетах вполне нормально можно написать

Comment: @CyberDoge Ну и библиотеки тоже. Я пока еще пишу, любым советам буду благодарен

Answer (score 0):

Java имеет в своем составе простенький `http` сервер.

Для Ваших нужд его вполне хватит:

```js
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8080), 0);
        server.createContext("/", new RootHandler());
        server.setExecutor(null); 
        server.start();
    }
}

public class RootHandler implements HttpHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange http) throws IOException {
        String response = "Ok";
        http.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
        OutputStream os = http.getResponseBody();
        os.write(response.getBytes());
        os.close();
    }
}
```

К нему Вы сможете постучаться из браузера или любого другого http клиента.

Comment: А смогу ли я из приложения Android отправлять запросы и получать ответы? Я просто еще не очень силен в этом. Http протоколом могут не только браузеры пользоваться?

Comment: @РоманРомашов так точно